# Parse (string) Function Call and Parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Suppose I have two links:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction();"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(1, 2, 'string');"></a>
```

My goal is to parse the `myFunction` call and get an array of the parameters. So from the first link I would want to get `[]` and from the second link I would want to get `[1, 2, 'string']`.

I already know how to get the `onclick` attribute into a string (we are using jQuery here), so that doesn't need to be part of the answer.

Basically:

```
var myCall="myFunction(1, 2, 'string')";
parseFunctionString(myCall); //[1, 2, 'string']
```

Define `parseFunctionString`. I am imagining this would msot easily be done with some sort of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this literally with the `arguments` keyword, within a function. For example:

```
function foo() {
    alert(arguments[0]);
}
foo('bar');
```

that will alert `'bar'`, since that's the first argument to the function. You can use the `arguments` keyword just like an array, but it won't have built-in methods like arrays do, so it won't have things like `.sort()`. More info can be found [**on MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Comment: Cool trick! Doesn't that mean I have to call myFunction though (so an eval maybe)?

Comment: for this approach, it would, yes. It is more reliable than using regex though, as you will run into problems when you'd start getting more complicated input than just numbers and strings in your input. You could make your `function myFunction() {return arguments;}` though, then executing it would return the arguments to you directly. You'd need to execute the function somewhere you can do something with that return value though.

Comment: @hellohellosharp According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments), this is part of JavaScript 1.1, which was released [in 1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history), so I'd say I'm quite sure it'll work in every browser. I am also quite sure that any site you'd make right now would look horrible in IE6, despite your best efforts. It's just not worth supporting IE6- anymore (or probably IE7-).

Comment: @hellohellosharp getting back to that final statement about supporting IE6, I just checked and it does look like most major sites still kind-of support IE6 in a way (it doesn't look *that* therrible in it). YouTube is completely broken, though, and Gmail already complains about me using an ancient browser when I use IE9 at school. So to correct my previous comment: you should keep the basic functionality, but if I were you, drop all further support for ancient browsers. It's not worth spending days coding for those 3 additional IE6-using viewers you'd win by giving them full functionality too.